# Are there any primary sources for the “passing constant by reference” behavior in old Fortran compilers?

Tags: history, programming, compilers, fortran, bugs

Occasionally I have heard references to a peculiarity of certain (old) Fortran compilers, with regards to subprogram argument passing. Here is an example, from [an answer to a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995476):

> Some early Fortran compilers implemented constants by using a constant pool. All parameters were passed by reference. If you called a function, e.g.
>
> ```
> f(1)
> ```
>
> The compiler would pass the address of the constant 1 in the constant pool to the function. If you assigned a value to the parameter in the function, you would change the value (in this case the value of 1) globally in the program. Caused some head scratching.

The C FAQ also mentions “FORTRAN's classic idiosyncrasy involving constants passed by reference” in [a footnote](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/fn17.html).

I have no problem believing that some compilers behaved this way. However, I would like to have some contemporaneous documents that confirm it. The nature of the document doesn't matter too much; I merely want confirmation from a non-anecdotal source (although some kind of manual would be ideal).

Comment: This was definitely still a feature of Fortran-77 compilers on PCs in the 1980s. To my knowledge, `gfortran` still uses this design, except that the constant pool is now mapped to read-only storage, so it is no longer possible to overwrite constants (which could be a source of hard-to-find bugs in the past!). I have searched manuals for old IBM and VMS Fortran compilers for the past 40 minutes, but have been unable to find any language that spells out these inner workings in explicit detail.

Comment: @njuffa Here's a compiler from 1966 that explicitly avoids the problem by passing constants by value: http://bitsavers.org/pdf/honeywell/series200/charlie_gibbs/027_Fortran_Compiler_D.pdf (page 6-11 (page 129 in the PDF)). This isn't really relevant; I just thought it was interesting.

Comment: DEC Fortran 77 allowed, with some limitations, overriding the default behavior (pass by reference) with `%VAL (arg)`.

Comment: IIRC, the IBM Fortran G and H compilers for S/360 and S370 had this feature, but (1) the "constant pool" was local to a subroutine/function, or a least local to a separate complication unit and (2) the exact (undetected but wrong) behavior depended on the optimization level you specified. No idea where if was documented (if anywhere) but it was a well known "programming bug" at the time.

Comment: My company produced a suite of Fortran tools in the 90s called PlusFort, and I remember this being a situation it looked out for.

Comment: This is a non-issue in modern Fortran (Fortran 90 or later), where you can declare parameter use as "in", "out" or "inout" in an interface block in the calling routine, and the  compiler will then check for violations.  If you don't declare an interface, the default is "inout" so attempting to use a constant argument is always a compilation error.

Comment: I've seen YouTube videos about people using a FORTRAN compiler on a rather ancient computer (IBM 1401 I think).  I wonder if those people could run a program that would actually demonstrate the behavior?  That would be the most definitive "primary source".

Comment: If you can find a book by Daniel McCracken, there's a good chance he discusses this.

Comment: I distinctly remember a hard-to-catch bug in one of my FORTRAN IV programs on IBM S/360 in the '70s where the constant 1 mysteriously behaved like 2... because constant 1 was passed as an argument to a SUBROUTINE that incremented it. Fond memories...

Comment: @alephzero That's not true. If there's no `intent` attribute (or the procedure doesn't have an explicit interface at all), the default isn't `intent(inout)`, but no intent at all (thus no compile-time checking). Doing it any other way would break loads and loads of existing and future code.

Comment: Re: VMS FORTRAN - the %VAL construction (and others) existed so that FORTRAN could call routines written in other languages (principally, I suppose, BLISS and MACRO-32) which might have value arguments.

Answer (score 9):

That fact is explicitly mentioned in the (Russian) book [Ошибки-ловушки при программировании на фортране, 1987](https://1lib.us/book/552950/f083b5?id=552950&secret=f083b5) (Errors and pitfalls in FORTRAN programming), page 88.

One of the puzzles was to make the sequence of operators

```
      J=1
      PRINT 1,J
  1   FORMAT(' J = ',I1)
```

print 0.

The provided solution was

```
      PROGRAM TASK
      CALL ZERO(1)
      J=1
      PRINT 1,J
  1   FORMAT(' J = ',I1)
      STOP
      END
      SUBROUTINE ZERO(K)
      K=0
      RETURN
      END
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm too young to remember *really old* Fortran compilers, but the behaviour that you described occurs in **all current Fortran compilers**. It's a core part of the language standard, so we can safely assume that any standard-conforming compilers in the past used to work this way as well.

Check out this example at https://godbolt.org/z/GKadP9rov (feel free to switch to Intel Fortran if you aren't a fan of gfortran):

```
subroutine foo(x)
    implicit none
    integer :: x

    x = 5
end subroutine

program test
    implicit none

    call foo(1)

    call bar(1)
end program
```

Because all Fortran subroutines by default accept all arguments by reference, the main program does not have any other option than to pass the constant `1` as a reference to a value in memory. The disassembly proves that the same location is used in both calls:

```
foo_:
…
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 5
…
.LC0:
        .long   1
MAIN__:
…
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    foo_
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    bar_
…
```

Of course, the constant will be placed into the read only data section on most modern platforms (except for those lacking an MMU). The write in `foo()` is thus going to trigger a segmentation fault at runtime.

Comment: This is only correct if you write Fortran ignoring the standards from Fortran 90 to present.  Here is a complete modern Fortran program (note, it is perfectly legal to write multiple statements on one line!) and the error message from gfortran:  "1 | program main ; call sub(1) ; end program main ; subroutine sub(i) ; integer, intent(out) :: i ; i = 42 ; end subroutine sub" "      |                        1
Error: Non-variable expression in variable definition context (actual argument to INTENT = OUT/INOUT) at (1)"

Comment: @alephzero But that's because you added the `intent` attribute, not because of Fortran 90+. Not specifying `intent` is perfectly standard conforming even in Fortran 2018, and in some situations it's the only reasonable option. (For example when interfacing with external non-Fortran libraries or in some cases of Fortran 2008 OOP code relying heavily on polymorphism.)

Comment: Would anything in the Standard forbid an implementation from passing `foo` the address of one storage location which was initialized to 1, and passing `bar` the address of another, or setting some storage location to 1 immediately before each call and passing its address?

Comment: Even in your grandfather's FORTRAN, the fact that a constant must be passed by reference does not imply that the reference has to be "the one and only" instance of that value.   Load the constant into a scratch location (on the stack if you have a stack) and set the argument to point to it.

Comment: And therefore, I regard passing a reference to a writeable "one and only" instance of a constant as a compiler bug - understandable in the context of the times, and who am I to criticize the pioneers, giants that they were, but nevertheless, it's still an implementation decision that does not match language semantics.

Comment: There must be an analogue in Algol-60 call by name arguments.  Given `procedure foo(a); a := 42;` what happens in typical compilers if you write `foo(0)` ?  I would hope the error is detected, preferable at compile time, otherwise at run time.

Comment: @another-dave A cursory reading of "Algol 60 Implementation" seems to indicate that in Randel and Russel's compiler you could modify a constant but it would be "local" to some extent; you can't globally affect the value of a constant.

Comment: Thanks; I was going to check that myself when I got around to it.

Comment: @texdr.aft - I tried it out on walgol and got a [FAIL 8](http://sw.ccs.bcs.org/KDF9/walgerrc.htm) (Real assigned to integer actual parameter called by name) at run time. This was not the error I would have expected, others seem more appropriate, but nevertheless, it was detected. I'll try the same thing on kalgol.

Comment: @texdr.aft - kalgol reports "FAIL 001 IN SECT.4.7.5.2." at run time.  As should be perfectly obvious :-), this means an invalid use of an expression called by name.  'SECT.4.7.5.2' is a fixed part of this error message, it does not refer to anything in the original program.  Compiler module?  Design spec? Documentation reference? No idea. Kalgol always was a little opaque.

Comment: @another-dave Section 4.7.5.2 of the Algol 60 report: “*A formal parameter which occurs as a left part variable in an assignment statement within the procedure body and which is not called by value can only correspond to an actual parameter which is a variable (special case of expression).*” I missed this when looking through the report yesterday, but it nicely answers your original inquiry about whether a constant called by name can be assigned to.

Comment: @texdr.aft - Oh, duh: it's a reference to the *Report*.  That's actually useful for an error message,

Comment: @another-dave Indeed. The only (modern) compiler I know of that provides citations in diagnostics is SBCL for Common Lisp.

Answer (score 5):

In the 1990s, I worked for a UK company (Polyhedron Software) that produced a suite of code analysis and refactoring tools for Fortran, marketed as [PlusFort](https://polyhedron.com/?product=plusfort#qa).

The GXCHK module performed static analysis of Fortran code to look for common errors, including:

> Subprogram argument mismatch or misuse (e.g. constant actual argument
> is illegally modified by subprogram).

Though I am no longer in contact with the company, I can remember this being an issue with Fortran-77 and before, as evidenced by the need of a QA tool to identify such bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Using an emulated [IBM 1130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1130) running DM2, I can confirm [Leo B.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/19929/are-there-any-primary-sources-for-the-passing-constant-by-reference-behavior-i/19949#19949)'s example. It took a little modification to run on the 1130:

```
// JOB
// FOR
*LIST SOURCE PROGRAM
*ONE WORD INTEGERS
      SUBROUTINE ZERO(K)
      K = 0
      RETURN
      END
// DUP
*DELETE             ZERO
*STORE      WS  UA  ZERO
// FOR
*LIST ALL
*IOCS(1132 PRINTER)
*ONE WORD INTEGERS
      J = 1
      WRITE(3, 2)
      WRITE(3, 1) J
      CALL ZERO(1)
      J = 1
      WRITE(3, 3)
      WRITE(3, 1) J
    1 FORMAT(' J = ', I1)
    2 FORMAT(' BEFORE -')
    3 FORMAT(' AFTER -')
      CALL EXIT
      END
// XEQ
```

The output of the program is:

```
BEFORE -
J = 1
AFTER -
J = 0
```

Since the value of `J` is only ever set to `1`, it's clear that the program has set the value of `1` to `0` …

Comment: You're restoring the value of 1 at the end of `IMDFY`. Please try the code in my answer (omitting the `PROGRAM` header and changing `PRINT` to `WRITE`, if necessary).

Comment: Thanks, @LeoB.! Your program, modified slightly, produced the expected if odd) result. I'll rewrite the answer

Comment: I do note that one Jimi Hendrix was aware of this, but evolved programming techniques to avoid problems: "[if six turned out the be nine, I don't mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_6_Was_9)".

Comment: I deleted a previous comment - I'd looked at this thread on an inadequate screen and thought the code had literally `3 = 1`.  Nevermind....

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is in support of the previous answers.  Hopefully, this is not the answer to some other question that was not asked.  The question was in reference to passing values without restriction in *old* compilers, but no reference was given to how old.  So lets start at the time of *really old.* This appears to be a non-standard feature used in Univac Fortran V (ca. 1973), and and also in Univac ASCII Fortran (ca. 1982).  The implementation of Univac Fortran V on the 1100 mainframe system, is the predecessor of Univac ASCII Fortran, and predominantly set the standard for Fortran 77.  Univac ASCII Fortran was the full version of Fortran 77 implemented on Univac 1108 system.

The feature mentioned in the question is very similar to the DEFINE statement in Univac Fortran V.  Lets think a minute... Here we are writing a main program and several subprograms called by the main program.  The nature of features like DEFINE was to allow control at the head of the main program, before stepping into execution, to set *the values* or *name references* of constants, variables and *functions* that were seen by the executable area of the main program and its subprograms. There were conflict restrictions the programmer had to consider in selecting variable naming conventions for the main program and subprograms, but DEFINE voided that restriction, but only for those constants, variables, and functions set by DEFINE. This gave the ability of the programmer to have program global control of DEFINE features to all areas of the program without passing arguments. Constants, variables, and functions set by DEFINE had unrestricted naming conventions. This was, at times, indispensable. This meant the programmer could set the *value* of a constant or variable without restriction, or DEFINE a function this way, and could access these defined features anywhere in the executable's environment.  These features were defined after setting the type but before the first executable in the main program. The highly proscriptive programming, compilation, and execution environment on the Univac system prevented the modification of memory areas outside of that allocated to the program by the compiler and executive operating system, a protective memory addressing issue. An attempted write-protection violation was a very serious issue.  DEFINE allowed a modification of this but only after the non-executable type-setting area of the program, *before the executable section of the program.*  This is consistent with the stated address passing action mentioned in the question.

Here is an example -

```
       DEFINE F(X,Y) = X + Y        a type definition of a function
```

followed by

```
       A = F(U*V,V)         results in A = U*V + V where A,U,V are *real*
```

or, for example

```
       D = F(I*J,K*I)   I,J,K are double precision, D is double precision by propagation
```

resulting in

```
       D = I*J + K*I     a double precision expression...
```

(Pretty cool! Especially if one does not have to mess with naming restrictions!!)

Univac Fortran V documentation states the following...

> 4.2 DEFINE PROCEEDURES
> A DEFINE generates inline code when it is referenced. Thus, it is analogous to an 1108 assembly procedure, rather than to an external or internal FUNCTION, which generates a closed subprogram.  The overhead of a subprogram is eliminated and the optimization capabilities of the compiler are allowed to operate.  The FORTRAN IV arithmetic statement functions are a subset of the DEFINE procedure.

Univac ASCII Fortran documentation shows the definition is little changed and gives the following characterization...

> The statement function generates inline code when it is referenced. This allows efficient references to the defining expression without referencing the expression each time.

In other words, DEFINE(expression) is a statement function definition that is global (i.e. unrestricted) within the allocated program environment. This would be extremely useful.

Examination of documentation for two other versions of Fortran 77 shows this feature is recognized as a Fortran 77 feature in Lahey Fortran, 1994, and also  recognized in Microsoft Fortran 5.0/5.1 1991, the predecessor of Compaq Fortran mentioned below.  The Lahey unavailability may likely be due to memory protection issues necessary for the operating-system environments of non-mainframe systems.

Examination of documentation for **Compaq Fortran version 6.6A** (May 2002), the industry standard pc-implementation of VAX Fortran 77 at the time, showed ***the feature is recognized*** as non-standard and operates in very much the same way mentioned in the question.

The following  is noted -

> 15.1.5  DEFINE and UNDEFINE Directives -
> The DEFINE directive creates a symbolic variable whose existence or value can be tested during conditional compilation.  The UNDEFINE directive removes a defined symbol.
> ...
> Rules and Behavior -
> DEFINE and UNDEFINE create and remove variables for use with the IF (or IF DEFINED) directive.  Symbols defined with the DEFINE directive are local to the directive.  They cannot be declared in the Fortran Program.
> Because Fortran programs cannot access the named variables, the names can duplicate Fortran keywords, intrinsic functions, or user-defined names without conflict.
> To test whether a symbol has been defined, use the IF DEFINED (name) directive.  You can assign an integer value to a defined symbol.  To test the assigned value of *name,* use the IF directive.  IF test expressions can contain most logical and arithmetic operators.
> Attempting to undefine a symbol that has not be defined produces a compiler warning.
> The DEFINE and UNDEFINE directives can appear anywhere in a program enabling and disabling symbol definitions.
> Examples  -   Consider the following

> ```
>    |DEC$ DEFINE  testflag  
>    |DEC$ IF DEFINED (testflag)  
>        WRITE( * , * ) 'Compiling first line'
> etc...
> ```

In the above example, IF DEFINED (testflag) is true, *Compiling first line* will be written.

The following documentation may be of interest...

Univac 1100 Series Fortran V Programmer Reference, UP-4060 Rev. 2, 1973

Sperry Univac Series 1100 Fortran (ASCII) Level 10-R1 Programmer Reference, UP-8244.2, 1982

Compaq Fortran Language Reference Manual, Order Number: AA-Q66SD-TK, September 1999

Compaq Fortran is now Intel Fortran.

So we went from *really old,* to maybe *not so old.*  Hope this answer was of some help...

Answer (score -4):

Here is an explicit example of the behavior mentioned by texdr.aft in their posted question...

```
       Program testzog
       !DEC$ DEFINE flag=3
  c ...... executable statements and some overly technical mumbo-jumbo
       call zog
       end
       subroutine zog
       !DEC$ IF (flag .eq. 3)
          WRITE (*,*) "This is compiled if flag equals 3."
       !DEC$ ELSEIF (flag .ge. 4)
          WRITE (*,*) "Or this compiled if flag greater than or equal to 4."
       !DEC$ ELSE
          WRITE (*,*) "Or this compiled if all preceding & conditions .FALSE."
       !DEC$ ENDIF
       END
```

Please note, DEFINE is a directive setting the value of flag equal to 3.  Poorly written compilers, or lack of familiarity with the Fortran language constructs, can produce results that are not expected.  In this case, however, results are as expected and consistent with the behavior mentioned by the OP in their question. The compiler used was Compaq Fortran version 6.6A.

For *testzog,*  DEFINE *flag=3* is a pre-executable directive setting the value of *flag* equal to 3.  As mentioned previously, a DEFINE directive, if used, must occur after setting the type for variables in the main program.  Note that the call to *subroutine zog* includes no reference to *flag* as a calling argument passed to *zog.*  Compilation and execution of *testzog* will result in "This is compiled if flag equals 3" for *flag=3* and "Or this compiled if flag greater than or equal to 4" for *flag=4.*  The value of *flag* determines executable actions in *subroutine zog* and indicates the value of *flag* is passed by reference, a compiler optimizing procedure invoked when program *testzog* and companion subroutine *zog* were compiled.

Comment: This seems to straddle off-topic. The question isn’t about conditional compilation.

Comment: You have apparently made a number of attempts to edit this and other people’s posts. Please [log in](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/login) to be able to edit your posts directly instead of asking moderators to review your edits.